# Why proxy not using on httpasyncclient

Tags: java, proxy

I use proxy on httpasyncclient like this:

```
final CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients
                .createDefault();
httpclient.start();
final HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.apache.org/");
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8888, "http");
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
request.setConfig(config);

final Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(request, null);
System.out.println("Response: " + future.get().getStatusLine());
```

But the request get the data not via the proxy. Why?
version:
httpasyncclient 4.0-beta4

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

```
final HttpClientContext localcontext = HttpClientContext.adapt(new BasicHttpContext());
localcontext.setRequestConfig(config);
final Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(request, localcontext, null);
```